# Python Locally Selenium Firefox code work but Dockerized not! Element Value does not Refresh always 0

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, docker, firefox

Locally and Dockerized i use the same versions

Python 2.7 + 
Selenium (i think latest where can i see it?) + 
Firefox (latest 59.01)

> **WORK ONLY FIREFOX LOCAL:**

**print returns correctly every second the right value**

```
//click button on webpage
elementbutton = driver.find_element_by_class_name("buttonclassname")
elementbutton.click()

(some code Blabla...)

//Read in a loop value from web element
progressvalue = driver.find_element_by_class_name("progress").text
print ("progress", progressvalue)
```

> **WORK FIREFOX AND CHROME LOCAL:**

**print returns correctly every second the right value**

```
//click button on webpage
elementbutton = driver.find_element_by_class_name("buttonclassname")
//this click does work in firefox and in chrome but uses Javascript click
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elementbutton)

(some code Blabla...)

//Read in a loop value from web element
progressvalue = driver.find_element_by_class_name("progress").text
print ("progress", progressvalue)
```

__

> **WORK NOT IN FIREFOX & NOT IN CHROME DOCKERIZED**

```
//click button on webpage
elementbutton = driver.find_element_by_class_name("buttonclassname")
elementbutton.click()

(some code Blabla...)

//Read in a loop value from web element
progressvalue = driver.find_element_by_class_name("progress").text
print ("progress", progressvalue)
```

> **WORK ONLY CHROME DOCKERIZED**

```
//click button on webpage 
elementbutton = driver.find_element_by_class_name("buttonclassname")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elementbutton)

(some code Blabla...)

//Read in a loop value from web element
progressvalue = driver.find_element_by_class_name("progress").text
print ("progress", progressvalue)
```

> **print returns the correct Value ONLY in chrome, in Firefox it returns always 0 the element does not refresh in Firefox**

it seems javascript maybe does not work or is not enabled?? 
Why??is this a gecko driver bug?

Comment: To be clear, the code works *locally* both in chrome and firefox... but in the *docker* environment, only Chrome works?

Comment: It probably points to a difference in your local environment versus the dockerized environment. Double check you are using the same version of firefox/geckodriver/selenium in the docker environment as you are locally. Are you running headless firefox both locally and in the container?

Comment: Updated my question, maybe its now better to understand.

i run it headless in firefox locally and it does work